# computing statistics at the schema level (11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This question is about computing statistics at the schema level (11g).Where are the schema level statistics stored .where can i retrieve the details of schema level statistics?and what is next step after gathering the statistics?

what i tried so far?

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats
           ('staging'
               ,estimate_percent => 20
                ,method_opt => 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE 1'
                ,block_sample => FALSE
                ,DEGREE => 32
                ,GRANULARITY => 'ALL'
                ,CASCADE => TRUE);
END;
/
```

what is the next step after this

Comment: You may want to consider using the default statistics gathering settings as much as possible.  For example, the default for `estimate_percent` uses a different algorithm that is likely faster and more accurate than 20%.

Answer (score 3):

Gathering statistics at the schema level means you have stats for all the tables in the schema (and all the indexes, because `CASCADE=>true`).  So you can find the values by querying the relevant data dictionary views (USER_TABLES, USER_INDEXES).

What is the next step?  Probably considering a refresh policy.  Your best approach is to automate this task.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm#i41282).